# Angular directive accessing controller - Strange 'ungoogled' message

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

I am trying to write an element directive, which I attach to a controller, in order to implement a sort-like behaviour. This is the directive

```
.directive('sorting', function () {
        return {
            restrict: 'E',
            scope: false, // I know I can omit this with no effect
            template: function (elem, attr) {
                return '<div><a href ng-click="setsort('+"'"+attr.sortkey+"'"+')">'+attr.headtext+'</a></div>'+
                      '<div ng-show="sortfield=='+"'"+attr.sortkey+"' || sortfield='-"+attr.sortkey+"'"+
                      '" ng-class="{'+"'sortreverse':sortreverse}"+'">&#9650;</div>';
                  }
            }
        });
```

`setsort(sortkey)`, `sortfield` and `sortreverse` belong to the scope of the controller.

Intended behaviour is that the caret (`&#9650;`) should only be displayed if sorting is selected for the specified element.

Sorting works as planned, however the caret displays in all sorting columns and I get a strange error message by angular, for which I cannot find any available feedback.

The error says:

```
Error: [$parse:lval] Trying to assing a value to a non l-value
http://errors.angularjs.org/1.4.5/$parse/lval
minErr/
[....a whole stacktrace ...]
"<div ng-show="sortfield=='yn_equivalent' || sortfield='-yn_equivalent'" ng-class="{'sortreverse':sortreverse}">"
```

*Fun fact*: The first line of the error is actually misspelled by angularjs (should be `assign` instead of `assing`)

The last line is part of the produced output by the directive, when summoned like this:

```
<sorting sortkey="yn_equivalent" headtext="SomeText"></sorting>
```

I am not very experienced with Angularjs, so perhaps you will need some more feedback, which I'll be glad to give.

Any clues?

Thanks.

Comment: For the sake of reusability, you should use an isolate scope with `&` to call parent scope functions. That would also free you from confusing template string concatenation.

Comment: That sounds like a good advice. Can you provide a link for me to look?

Comment: Here's a video from egghead.io https://egghead.io/lessons/angularjs-isolate-scope-expression-binding

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In your `ng-show`, the comparison after the OR operator is missing an equals sign. You should probably use `===` for both of those anyway.

Comment: You get the answer selected, I get the price for the `blind of the year`. Thanks a lot. Triple `===` was not necessary.